# set-frame-height in .emacs doesn't have any effect

Tags: debugging, emacs, dot-emacs

I recently updated from GNU Emacs 20.7.1 to 23.2 (Yeah, I'm a little slow changing.)
My .emacs begins with

```
 (set-frame-height (selected-frame) 60)  
 (set-frame-width (selected-frame) 90)  
 (set-frame-position (selected-frame) 50 20)
```

This works with 20.7.1, but not 23.2
I've run with -debug-init and get no errors for my .emacs file.

If I select the first three lines of the .emacs file in a buffer and eval-region, the window moves to the location in line 3 and width is set to 90. If I eval-region again, the height is set to 60.

While I haven't tested every other line in the .emacs, it appears that the balance of the file evaluates normally at init time.

(OS = Windows Vista)

Comment: After some experimentation, it appears that this line - (set-default-font "-*-Lucida Console-normal-r-*-*-13-*-96-96-c-*-iso8859-1")
breaks the set-frame-height or set-frame-size commands. By moving the set-default-font line above the set-frame-height, everything works. Then I tried to add (tool-bar-mode nil) and that broke set-frame-height no matter where I put it in the .emacs file.

Answer (score 3):

Weird. Looks like a bug.

Setting width and height together resolves the problem for me.

`(set-frame-size (selected-frame) 90 60)`